# Should I use dispatch on return type of action in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, redux-thunk

I confused on using dispatch.Please see my below code.

```
export function getUserInfo(isDeviceinfo) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_DEVICE_MODEL_RESET,
            isDeviceinfo,
        });
    };
}
```

or

```
export function getUserInfo(isDeviceinfo) {
    return => {
        type: REQUEST_DEVICE_MODEL_RESET,
        isDeviceinfo,
    };
}
```

Now which one I should use.Please suggest me.

Comment: Your second example isn't valid syntax - if you want to return a zero argument arrow function, you need to write `() => {}`. If you meant to return an object instead, remove the `=>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to perform any asynchromous operation use this,

```
export function getUserInfo(isDeviceinfo) {
      return{
             type: REQUEST_DEVICE_MODEL_RESET,
             isDeviceinfo,
         };
    }
```

If you need to perform asynchronous operation use dispatch.

```
function getUserInfo(isDeviceinfo) {
    return (dispatch)=>{
       //perform a async operation like this http call
        return fetch(SOME_URL).then(j=>j.json()).then((d)=>{
             dispatch({
                 type: REQUEST_DEVICE_MODEL_RESET,
                 isDeviceinfo,
             })
        })


    }
}
```